# Error: unexpected input in "grps <- c(rep(“" ) in my rep statement

Tags: r

I'm using the 3.2.0 version for windows.

I am attempting to use the rep command to repeat Grp1, Grp2, Grp3, Grp4 eight t imes. I am using this to run an ANOVA with four groups this is the line of code that I used.

```
grps <- c(rep(“Grp1”, 8),rep(“Grp2”, 8), rep(“Grp3”, 8),rep(“Grp4”, 8))
```

I've tried using each=8 for each rep but everything I try gives me this error:

> **Error: unexpected input in "grps <- c(rep(“"**

Comment: Those look like weird quotation marks to me. Note how the double quotes in R's error message are straight and yours are curly...?

Comment: Change your quotes `“` to `"`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your quotes are fancy curly-quotes (at least when I copied and pasted them into my R).

This works fine for me:

```
grps <- c(rep("Grp1", 8),
          rep("Grp2", 8),
          rep("Grp3", 8),
          rep("Grp4", 8))
```

You could try replacing your double quotes with single quotes (' instead of ").

Comment: Yup - the problem is the fancy quotes. Here's a more compact version of code that achieves the same output: `rep(paste0("Grp", 1:4), each = 8)`

Comment: Thanks the paste0 function did the trick!